# Use reduce to sum values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reduce, cumulative-sum

I have this array of objects:

```
const data = [
  {val: 40, color: 'red'},
  {val: 5, color: 'green'},
  {val: 55, color: 'lime'}
]
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
const result = [
  {val: 40, color: 'red'},
  {val: 45, color: 'green'},
  {val: 100, color: 'lime'}
]
```

So each item should have the same color and the cumulative value of previous data.

This is what I try:

```js
const data = [
  {val: 40, color: 'red'},
  {val: 5, color: 'green'},
  {val: 55, color: 'lime'}
]

// const result = [
//   {val: 40, color: 'red'},
//   {val: 45, color: 'green'},
//   {val: 100, color: 'lime'}
// ]

const result = data.reduce((r, value, i) => {
    const { val, color } = value
    const cumVal = i === 0 ? val : r[i - 1].val
    const newDatum = { val: cumVal, color }
    return newDatum
}, data[0])

console.log(result)
```

Where is the error? Why `r[i - 1]` is undefined?

Comment: The seed `data[0]` is incorrect. It should be `[]` because you want it to result into a new array. Additionally, build up this array, you need to `return [...r,  newDatum]`, not `newDatum`

Comment: `reduce` function return a single value. in this case, you need to use `map` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had four issues in your code:

- In this line `const cumVal = i === 0 ? val : r[i - 1].val` you should assign `0` as a default value, not `val`
- In this line `const newDatum = { val: cumVal, color }` you need to add `val` to `cumVal`
- As an initial value, you should pass an empty array, not the first element of your `data` array, because you want to have an array as a result, not an object
- You need to return the `r` in every iteration, not `newDatum` - again, you want to have an array in the end, not an object

Here is a fixed version:

```js
const data = [
  {val: 40, color: 'red'},
  {val: 5, color: 'green'},
  {val: 55, color: 'lime'}
]

// const result = [
//   {val: 40, color: 'red'},
//   {val: 45, color: 'green'},
//   {val: 100, color: 'lime'}
// ]

const result = data.reduce((r, value, i) => {
    const { val, color } = value
    const cumVal = i === 0 ? 0 : r[i - 1].val
    const newDatum = { val: val + cumVal, color }
    r.push(newDatum);
    return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

You start the reduce with a single element, which is not an array.

Instead, you could take a closure over `sum` and map new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ val: 40, color: 'red' }, { val: 5, color: 'green' }, { val: 55, color: 'lime' }],
    result = data.map(
        (sum => ({ val, color }) => ({ val: sum += val, color }))
        (0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result2 = data.reduce((acc, { val, color }, i) => {
    val += (i>0) ? acc[i - 1].val: 0;
    return acc.concat([{ val, color }])
}, [])
```

the solution to your problem.

issues:

1. wrong initial value
2. returning object

> though I think Map would be a better choice here.